# angular radio button group set model for each group

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

I have an UI, where I need to display a radio buttons(each radio button group) with only one  tag which runs in ng-repeat. I need to display 3 radio groups and I want to set the model for each group. Below is the code.

```
    <div  class="radio" data-ng-repeat="item in selItem.surveyRefData" >                    
                    <label for="{{radiolabel}}">
                      <input type="radio"                    
                      data-ng-value={{item.vm}}                       
                      data-ng-change="SetSelectItemsRadio(selItem, item)"                     
                      data-ng-model="????"/>{{item.dm}}                  
                       </label>
  </div>
```

Comment: do you have 3 ng-repeat for your groups or just one? @user1015388

Comment: I have one ng-repeat which displays the different radio groups

Comment: @Yaser do you have any idea how to do this with one ng-repeat

Comment: There is no clean way of doing that with one `ng-repeat`. Why you are not willing to use 2?

Comment: Our UI is unique that, backend passes what kind of controller should be displayed on UI, depending on that how many ever those type of controller are there, those should get rendered.